# Why am I getting an error while running the following SQL code

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to query a public dataset "new_york_citibike" on google bigquery to return the num_of_bikes_available and average num_of_bikes_available for each station_id but when I am running the code I am geeting an error:

> SELECT list expression references column num_bikes_available which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:5]

The SQL code is:

```
SELECT
    num_bikes_available,
    station_id,
    AVG(num_bikes_available) AS avg_num_bikes_available
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
GROUP BY 
    station_id;
```

Comment: You need to aggregate `num_bikes_available` like `sum(num_bikes_available)`

Comment: But why should I aggregate it. Can't I just select the num_bikes_available column. Since this column represents the number of bikes available. Sorry if I sound silly.

Comment: What value shoule the DB display for  `num_bikes_available`? There are multiple for every  `station_id`. The lowest, the biggest, ...?

Comment: I get it. But according to the dataset num_bikes_available represents the Number of bikes available for rental for station_id. And I also checked there are 1584 distinct station_id in the dataset. Also if aggregation is required then why does this query doesn't return a error. "SELECT station_id,num_bikes_available,(SELECT AVG(num_bikes_available) FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` ) AS avg_num_bikes_available FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`"

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery if you are using  GROUP BY clasue every other column has to be either GROUPED BY or you have to do some calculation like: SUM/MIN/MAX... etc, so in this case you have to do:

```
SELECT
    station_id,
    SUM(num_bikes_available) AS sum_num_bikes_available,
    AVG(num_bikes_available) AS avg_num_bikes_available
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
GROUP BY 
    station_id;
```

I also suggest you to switch station_id column to the first column because it will look much clearer this way.

Comment: But according to the dataset num_bikes_available represents the Number of bikes available for rental for station_id. And I also checked there are 1584 distinct station_id in the dataset. Also if aggregation is required then why does this query doesn't return a error. `SELECT station_id,num_bikes_available,(SELECT AVG(num_bikes_available) FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations ) AS avg_num_bikes_available FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to organize your table by station_id? If so, it may be more useful to use ORDER BY rather than GROUP BY since station_id is an integer class.

```sql
SELECT
  station_id,
  num_bikes_available,
  (SELECT
  AVG(num_bikes_available)
  FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`) AS avg_num_bikes_available

FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`

ORDER BY
  station_id
```

This will show the list from lowest to highest station_id.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in the `station_id` column in the dataset as its type is string and there is about 85 rows display id like (66dd6441-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c
).
You can make a new table resulted from this query

```
SELECT
*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` 
WHERE station_id NOT LIKE '_____%'
```

and save it in your own project and replace it in your query.